# How to get row(s) with max or null value in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I would like get all rows with **h_id** max value or NULL if present there. For example result for table below will be:

```
fid     |h_id    |
--------|--------|
13374976|        |
13377411|66666666|
```

I tried to write select statement but it returns only max values. How should I extend subselect in this statement for getting correct values?

```
select
    a.fid,
    a.h_id
from
    my_table a
where
    a.h_id = (
    select
        MAX(sub.h_id)
    from
        my_table sub
    where
        sub.FID = a.FID)
group by
    a.fid,
    a.h_id
order by
    a.fid
```

```
fid     |h_id    |
--------|--------|
13374976|58280198|
13374976|58372885|
13374976|        |
13377411|58280199|
13377411|66666666|
```

Comment: Is your question only related to PostgreSQL? If so, remove the Microsoft SQL Server tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to answer your question, I did the following (fiddle available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d7738d740d76a7690fce800fcfbdcb9a)):

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  fid INTEGER NOT NULL,
  h_id INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT h_id_uq UNIQUE (h_id)
);
```

populate the table - added a couple of extra records for testing purposes.

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES 
(13374976, 58280198),
(13374976, 58372885),
(913374976,  NULL  ),
(23, NULL),
(913377411, 58280199),
(13377411, 66666666),
(13377411, 77777777);
```

And the ran the following query:

```
SELECT fid, h_id FROM test
WHERE h_id = 
(
  SELECT MAX(h_id)
  FROM test
)
UNION
SELECT fid, h_id
FROM test 
WHERE h_id IS NULL;
```

Result:

```
fid            h_id
23             NULL
13377411       77777777
913374976      NULL
```

This provides the answer you require - there is an assumption that h_id is `UNIQUE` or else you'll have to do a `GROUP BY` fid - but that's a different question.

In future, could you please provide a fiddle with your table structures and your (presumably) sample data - it makes life much easier for those trying to help you and eliminates duplication of effort as well as providing a [Single Source of Truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth).

Also, although it doesn't make much difference in this case, could you also please provide your PostgreSQL version as a tag or in the question itself - it can be helpful!

p.s. welcome to the forum!